# Getting a value of a certain JSON object field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
var definitionsObject = {"company" : "Some information about company"};
```

This object will actually contain a lot of definitions, not just one. And I also have the following event handler for a link click which has a custom "data-name" attribute containing the term "company":

```
$(".definitinOpener").click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var hintID = $this.attr("data-name");
      var hintText = definitionsObject.hintID;
});
```

So, what I'm trying to do is get the value of "data-name" custom attribute of the clicked link, go to the `definitionsObject` object and get the value of the field which is equal to the "data-name" attribute value. However in this way I'm always getting "undefined".

Could anybody please help me to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: That's an object literal, not a "JSON object".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up a value in an object in two ways.

```
var obj = { key : 'value' }
var lookup = 'key'

console.log( obj.lookup ) //undefined
console.log( obj.key ) //value
console.log( obj[lookup] ) //value
```

You probably want this:

```
var hintText = definitionsObject[hintID];
```

Answer (score 0):

`definitionsObject.hintID` does not return `definitionsObject[hintId]`, it will return `definitionsObject['hintId']`.

I belive you can accomplish this with

```
var hintText = definitionsObject[hintId];
```

instead of

```
var hintText = definitionsObject.hintID;
```